# issue updating html after ajax response received

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

After having multiple issues requesting data from my server I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564179/ajax-request-not-receiving-response). Never got that code to work so I ended up rewriting the whole ajax request and now I'm able insert data in the database.

However, the issue I'm having now is that the responseText that is being sent back to my ajax request is not updating my html.

At the end of my registration script, after all values have been inserted into the database, I have this code which tests to make sure the registration email has been sent to the user and sends a string back to the ajax request:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "email_success";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "email_failure";
    exit;
}
```

Once a response has been received I have this condition to test what string has been returned:

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        if (hr.responseText == "email_success") {
             window.scrollTo(0,0);
             gebi("signupform").innerHTML = "<p>Sign up successful. Check you email to activate you account.</p>";
        } else {
             gebi("status").innerHTML = hr.responseText;
             gebi("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm have is that the `"signup_success"` string is not being recognised as `true` and instead it fires this else statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to do console.log(hr.responseText) or alert(hr.responseText)

Comment: Perhaps there's more html being echoed than that in your php if..else. Is there a reason why you're not using some library like jquery to handle ajax requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your error is that you have to trim the response text before do the comparation.

Trim code:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

and then

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var responseText = hr.responseText.trim();
        if (responseText == "email_success") {
             window.scrollTo(0,0);
             gebi("signupform").innerHTML = "<p>Sign up successful. Check you email to activate you account.</p>";
        } else {
             gebi("status").innerHTML = hr.responseText;
             gebi("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your a legend! Thank you.